# Does anyone know where the QT (4.7) headers and libraries are located (i.e. paths) on the mac?

Tags: c++, qt, macos, qt4

For all my trying, I just can't find the damn things.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Quick sanity check: stock Mac OS X doesn’t ship Qt, so you need to install it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it looks like this:

> /usr/include
>
> /Library/Frameworks
>
> /Developer/Tools/Qt
>
> /usr/local/Qt4.7
>
> /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins

I found this in the file qtdirs.out which happened to lie in my root. Not sure about when it was generated, either during Qt's installation or during PyQt's installation.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to find these things is to use the `mdfind -name` command. I don’t know what QT’s headers are called, but if you are looking for, say `qt4.h`, run the following Terminal command:

```
mdfind -name qt4.h
```

This will use Spotlight to find all indexed files named `qt4.h`.

Alternatively, you can try regular Spotlight (the magnifying glass icon in the upper-right corner), however, this does not show you *all* files that Spotlight knows about. The command-line `mdfind` will show you those files.